# Wordpress docker with empty responses to HTTP requests

Tags: apache, docker

I originally posted this on Stack Overflow but felt it would be better here.

I've got a Wordpress docker container that isn't really responding. Trying to access it from the browser results in an empty page. No 404 or anything. Trying curl from either a computer on the network, or the server itself returns an empty response as well.

I've done a `docker exec -ti container bash` into it to try and run curl from within, and it's also empty. `/var/www/html` is populated, and the single entry in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` is pointing to the `/var/www/html` directory.

There are no errors in `/var/log/apache2/errors` to speak of, which isn't helpful.

I've done the usual `netstat -tlpn` to verify that the server is listening on the correct port, and it is. I've also changed the addresses in the wp database to localhost, to see if that was causing the issue, but that didn't change anything.

Here's my docker-compose.yml, which is very simple

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: PASSWORD
       MYSQL_DATABASE: DBNAME
       MYSQL_USER: USERNAME
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: PASSWORD

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     volumes:
       - ./upload.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
     ports:
       - "80:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:PORT
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: USERNAME
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: PASSWORD
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: DBNAME
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

I'm at a loss as to what to check next, and am hoping to find ideas here.

Comment: The WP container should have a _license.txt_ and _readme.html_ in `/var/www/html`, can you access them through browser/curl?

Comment: I cannot. Tried both files to no avail.

Comment: I take that back. In my early morning stupor, I reversed the extensions. The files are loadable.

Comment: I've verified that it's loading PHP files with a phpinfo() test.

Comment: So the server is running, PHP is working. Only WordPress itself is making problems?

Comment: Correct. I just remove all plugins and themes by moving the directories and still getting the issue, so it's not that.

Comment: I fixed it. I hate to say it, but I don't know how. I played with the site_url & home settings in the DB and it ended up working.

Comment: Glad it works now :) Off topic: You should consider adding at least one volume to the `wordpress` service, otherwise you run the risk of losing everything you've done inside the container. But this is purely docker and not WP related.

Comment: Yes, I'll do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer was a messed up entry in either site_url or home within the MySQL database. I changed those settings and the issue was resolved.